# magento does not create session when using add to cart button from different site

Tags: php, magento

I am generating add to cart buttons from a mans site separate from magento. for some reason when you click the add the cart button, it does not recognize a session so the enable cookies page show. if you refresh the page and on afterward , it works. how can i activate the session when using a external add the cart button.

Comment: please post the code that you are using. make sure to format it as code using the StackOverflow editor.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code it is hard to know precisely, but in general terms, you need to look at the procedure which checks the session and explicitly initialise the magento session when the button is clicked.

One thing to note: If the buttons are on another domain, you may have problems with the session being transferred from one to another, which  will make PCI compliance a little more tricky.

My advice would be to take a look at the API to see how you can connect into your Magento application in a clean way.